# Import to clean postgres database incomplete

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have been trying to copy a postgresql database to my local machine to use for some testing. I first generated a dump using `pg_dump -h myhost -U myuser -f mydump.sql mydatabasename` and then tried to load it into my machine using `psql -d mynewdb -f mydump.sql`.

This ran fine however when I inspect the tables, I only have a very small portion of the data inserted. I checked the plain text dump and there is definitely more data in there. I also tried using `--format=t` and `--format=c` with `pg_restore` but had the same issue.

Does anyone have an idea as to how I can get all the data from the dump?

Comment: Inspect the mydump.sql if its less in size and compare the missing item (find the missing pattern/type). Then, it would help https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-pgdump.html

Comment: @Spike I've checked it and it's missing a lot from most tables. This is a big db so I would prefer the restore to just work rather than having to manipulate the dump file manually.

Comment: You need to drop everything from the target database before importing. When using a plain text dump (aka "SQL dump") you can do that by add the `--clean` parameter to the `pg_dump` call. If using the custom format, this can be done by using the `--clean` parameter for `pg_restore`

Comment: Is your data in the `.sql` file or not? If it is then the `restore` has a problem. If it is not, then the `dump` has a problem. It is probably more a `restore` than `dump` problem but it would be good to first do this dichotomy step. Are both databases exactly the same version and environments?

Comment: All the data was in the `.sql` file, so it is just the `restore` that was broken. I've managed to get around it for my use case using an application level export rather than using postgresql though it was still an annoying problem to have.